# Django: How to prompt user during migration?

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm writing a migration that converts a ForeignKeyField to a ManyToManyField. Part of this migration involves data migration. Migrating forwards is easy and requires no user interaction. Migrating backwards however ideally requires the user to pick which of the m2m to become the foreign key (ie there's a recognition of data loss).

Additionally. the user performing the migration might want to be given a python shell so they can poke around and look at objects before answering the question.

And some users might not care, and might not want to be prompted at all. (ie they use the --no-input argument during migration)

Does django have a built in mechanism to do all this? I can't find anything, but at the back of my mind it seems like something I've seen somewhere.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to migrate backwards? Although Django offers that functionality, it is frequently "left blank". Especially since if you later wish to revert the migration, a lot of things are changed, and it usually makes more sense to see this as a "forward" migration.

Comment: Backward migrations are mostly used in development, when you made a change that you later decide to revert and do differently or you have to switch to a different branch to review code that hasn't got the change yet. It's not common to see them applied in production, except during a rollback due to a "crisis" in which case the data usually hasn't changed yet and making assumptions in the backward migration is fine (e.g. just pick the first m2m to assign the fk since very likely there's only one anyway). Even if you distribute your app, I wouldn't bother to make backward migrations "perfect".

Comment: Yes it's primarily for development.

Comment: Then you shouldn't care about the data that much. Just pick the first record so the backwards migration works. TL;DR no there isn't a way.

Comment: take that back, there is a way: look at the `InteractiveMigrationQuestioner` in **django.db.migrations.questioner**, subclass it to add your own question (e.g. `ask_which_instance`) and call it to prompt the user for making a choice. Nice exercise, but a lot of work for questionable utility :-)

Comment: @dirkgroten That's the one! Write that as an answer, I'll accept it and you'll earn valuable internet points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to interactively ask for user input during a migration, you can use the `InteractiveMigrationQuestioner` in **django.db.migrations.questioner**.

Subclass it, add your own question (e.g. `ask_which_instance`) with its arguments. You can use the `_ask_choice` method to let users choose from multiple options.

Then in your `backward()` method, instantiate it and call your question method (which should return the user's input, e.g. 1, 2 or 3 if you offer 3 choices).